# Problems with outputting error after submit empty fields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have a problem with my script, the only problem is outputting error.
the error just bricks after submit_button. so that means when the fields are empty it has to output error and it works but the problem the output just bricks

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="text_field1" />
  <input type="text" id="text_field2">
  <button type="submit" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <p id="error_resp"></p>
</form>
<script>
  $("#submit_button").click(function() {
    if ($("#text_field1").val() == "")
      $('#error_resp').text('please fill the required field');
    else if ($("#text_field2").val() == "")
      $('#error_resp').text('please fill the required field');
    else
      return true;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure I understand what your issue is, but at least, you'll need to return false on form submit to prevent to post data (inside your if conditions for minimal changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your `form` HTML.

1. You are not using `preventDefault()` method which will prevent the default behavior of a form so the inout can be validated.
2. Also, you do not need check empty input like `== ""` You can just `!` to say if my input is empty then show error message
3. You are displaying errors in `error_resp` ideally use `.html` to clear the previous message and replace with new message

You can read more about `.html` [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Run snippet to below to see it working.

```js
$("#submit_button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$("#text_field1").val()) {
    $('#error_resp').html('please fill the first required field');
  } else if (!$("#text_field2").val()) {
    $('#error_resp').html('please fill the second required field');
  } else {
    $('#myForm').submit();
    console.log('All looking good. Form will submit now')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="filename.php">
  <input type="text" id="text_field1" />
  <input type="text" id="text_field2">
  <button type="submit" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
  <p id="error_resp"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: how can i make it submit, coz it seems working but not submitting

Comment: @michkent See the updated answer. Just use `.submit` to submit your from page to the backend file like `php` on `else` condition.